# Print bash script output to log file

Tags: 14.04, bash

I have bash script:

```
echo "Hello world"
ls -la
```

How to ask this script print `stdout` and `stderr` to `info.log` file?

How to ask this script print `stdout` and `stderr` to `info.log` file and screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the script like so to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to the file.

```bsh
./yourScript.sh > info.log 2>&1
```

To redirect to a file as well as the console, you can use `tee`

```bsh
./yourScript.sh 2>&1 | tee info.log
```

Comment: In `bash` `script.sh &> info.log` is short for the above.